# get property value from object collection list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get value property from object collection using one of property of object collection.

using Linq what will be the query on **SupplierSettingsList**

```
public class SupplierSettings
{
    private string Key;
    private SupplierSettingsPropertyEnum property;
    private string Value;
}

List<SupplierSettings> SupplierSettingsList =new List<SupplierSettingsDto>();

SupplierSettingsList .Add
(new SupplierSettings{Key="1",property=SupplierSettingsPropertyEnum.Name,Value="Name"});

SupplierSettingsList .Add
(new SupplierSettings{Key="2",property=SupplierSettingsPropertyEnum.StartTime,Value="7PM"});

SupplierSettingsList .Add
(new SupplierSettings{Key="3",property=SupplierSettingsPropertyEnum.EndTime,Value="10PM"});

SupplierSettingsList .Add
(new SupplierSettings{Key="4",property=SupplierSettingsPropertyEnum.Interval,Value="45"});
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear at the moment. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I want property value of object whos property is property=SupplierSettingsPropertyEnum.Interval

Comment: You might want to post what you're trying to do with this design and why you choose to do it this way.  I have a sneaking suspicion that there is a better way, but can not be sure without more information.

Comment: @PramodChoudhari Remember if you got your answer then mark it as answer

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if it works for you...

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for something as below

```
var SupplierSettingsVales = SupplierSettings.
Where(x=>x.property==SupplierSettingsPropertyEnum.Interval)
    .Select(x=>x.Value);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can written as

```
var results = from o in SupplierSettingsList
              where o.property == SupplierSettingsPropertyEnum.Interval
              select o.Value;
```

Also you can find `LINQ Query samples` in your `C: drive`
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Samples\1033`
in that `CSharpSamples.zip` unzip and build the project, located in folder `LinqSamples`

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = SupplierSettings
  .Where(x=>x.property==SupplierSettingsPropertyEnum.Interval)
  .Select(x=>x.Value);
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do:

```
var query =
    from ss in SupplierSettingsList
    where ss.property == SupplierSettingsPropertyEnum.Interval
    select ss.Value;
```

I'm a little dubious about your `SupplierSettings` as it doesn't seem to be a very good example of OOP. It may be better that you think about your object design rather than work out this query. Just a suggestion.